# Hero image is covering all text and logo?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, z-index

I'm super new to coding, and I can't for the life of me figure out why the hero image covers the other content, even using z-index.

[Here is what the web page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQH1s.jpg) but the hero image covers the logo, top nav bar, and header/description text about the first castle.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header,
footer,
main {
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font: 700 30px 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

header p {
  font: 18px/1.2 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header ul {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div p {
  margin: 0;
}

main p {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h2,
main div p {
  color: #fff;
}

footer ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

footer li,
header li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

footer a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s;
}

header ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

footer a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

header a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

footer nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 760px;
  left: 460px;
}

main div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 126px;
  top: 658px;
}

main div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 472px;
  top: 658px;
}

main div:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 817px;
  top: 658px;
}

main div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
}

.img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 110px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.img2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 320px 10px 100px 15px;
}

.twitter {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  right: -335px;
}

.facebook {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  right: -295px;
}


/*.logo {display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
        z-index: 2;}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- oxygwen, July 17, 2020 -->
  <title>Castle Explorers European Tours</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="The home page for Castle Explorers, a tour company that takes travelers to see famous castles in Europe." />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" width="124" height="55" alt="Castle Explorers" /></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">UPCOMING EVENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SCHEDULE TOURS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Moritzburg Castle</h1>
    <p>Enjoy the grandeur of this Baroque palace located on a beautiful lake in Germany.</p>
    <a href="#"><img class="img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" width="1040" height="400" alt="Moritzburg Castle" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" width="320" height="300" alt="Mont Saint Michel Abbey" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" width="320" height="300" alt="Eilean Donan Castle" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" width="320" height="300" alt="Neuschwanstein Castle" /></a>
    <div class="div1">
      <h2>Mont Saint-Michel Abbey</h2>
      <p>Visit the Normandy coast and this magical castle from the middle ages.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <h2>Eilean Donan Castle</h2>
      <p>Explore the 13th century castle of Clan Mackenzie where three sea lochs meet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <h2>Neuschwanstein Castle</h2>
      <p>Be enchanted by the Bavarian castle that was the inspiration for Cinderella's Castle at Disney World.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#"><img class="facebook" src="facebook.png" width="17" height="24" alt="facebook link" /></a>
      <a href="#"><img class="twitter" src="twitter.png" width="26" height="24" alt="twitter link" /></a>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Specs:

> Summary
> You are coding the home page for Castle Explorers.
>
> Use any combination of positioning, float, and the box model to create the layout.
>
> This layout could draw from any of the material in the course.
>
> Specifications
>
> Name the HTML5 file index.html
>
> All of the CSS will be in an external file referenced via a link tag; naming this main.css or styles.css is a typical file name for a stylesheet used by an entire website (if we were to build out the site, which will not be happening, all the CSS would go into this one file).
>
> In the head region of the page include a comment with your name and the date.
> Provide a good meta description.
>
> The attached screenshots provide the title tag value to use.
>
> This layout is fixed width centered. It is 1040 pixels wide. Disable margin and padding on body (set them to 0).
>
> Two Google Web Fonts are used. 'Moritzburg Castle' uses Roboto Slab and has a weight of 700. All other text uses Open Sans and is either 400 or 700 for weight.
> As noted in the summary, your approach to this will involve any combination of positioning, float, and box model.
>
> The graphics are all in the attached zip archive and screenshots are provided for Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.
>
> As you explore the screenshots you may want to use a graphics program such as Paint.NET to determine placement of text, graphics, etc. There is a free version of that software you can download. Mac users could try Pinta. There are also dozens of other options. Some people like to use the Perfect Pixel browser extension to overlay a screenshot over your rendering.
>
> 'Moritzburg Castle' is an h1 that is 30px and has font-weight 700. As noted previously, it is the only text using Roboto Slab. The default line-height is fine to use there.
>
> The text below it is 18px Open Sans with 1.2 line-height.
>
> The top navigation is an unordered list. Text size is 15px with 1.2 line-height.
> The text for the series of 3 castles (for their names) are h2 that are 17px, 700 font weight, and 1.2 line-height.
>
> The text below those castle name h2's are 13px with 1.2 line-height.
>
> I recommend using rgba(0,0,0,0.4) to create the transparency for the h2's and their additional text. The padding there is 10px on all sides except the right-hand side, which is 5px.
>
> The footer links are also an unordered list, but because they are centered you may want to display those list items as inline-block. There is 40px between them, but keep in mind that inline-block will render a single space if it exists in the code, so eliminating white space between list items is recommended.
>
> The footer links are 15px and their color is #666.
>
> The top navigation and the footer links all change to #000 on hover and focus; give them a CSS transition of: color .4s ease-in
>
> The social media icons don't need to be an unordered list; they can just be a pair of anchors containing the images. There is 15px of space between the icons, but if they are displayed inline-block remember to eliminate white space between those anchors to avoid introducing extra space.
>
> All links will use href="#". The linked elements are:
>
> Logo
> Top Navigation
> All four castle photos
> Footer Navigation
> Social media icons
>
> Make sure that image alt attribute values are appropriate and descriptive.
> HTML structural elements (header, main, footer, nav) need to be used appropriately.

Any ideas? Getting desperate because it's due in a few hours...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
h1 {
  font: 700 30px 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;      << Change to this
  display: inline-block;

.img1 {
  position: absolute; << Remove this 
  top: 0;
  right: 110px;
  z-index: 1000;
```

This happens to you because you are using position: absolute; for your image along with the H1 text which makes the image appear above other elements you just have to remove that image position: absolute; and insert your h1 tag into the image div itself or make it position: relative;

Tell me if this fixes your issue I checked it with chrome dev tools :D